# Meaning of 'the recovery might not last'

Tags: this-last

> Without a large amount of spending, the recovery might not last.

I don't understand the meaning of the above sentence. Could someone help me to figure it out?

Comment: Provide more context. Sounds like someone's taking about someone falling ill again after recovering.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence almost surely arose in the context of a discussion of economics. If so, there is nothing mysterious about the wording. In particular, "the recovery" refers to the national economy's recovery from a state of near-depression—which in the United States followed on the heels of the bursting of the housing speculation bubble in 2008.

The writer is simply saying that unless a large amount of spending occurs (either in the form of the country's citizens buying things or in the form of the country's government making public funds available to businesses for specific projects) to bolster the economic recovery, the economy might sink back into a severe recession. The word *last* (which your tag choice suggests you are not sure about) simply mean "continue."

---

I did a bit of online checking and discovered that this question is from a standardized test, the GMAT. Here is the test question (together with the multiple-choice options available for completing it):

> Although a surge in retail sales _____________________ underway, many economists say that without a large amount of spending the recovery might not last.
>
> (A) have raised hopes that there is a recovery finally
>
> (B) raised hopes for there being a recovery finally
>
> (C) had raised hopes for a recovery finally being
>
> (D) has raised hopes that a recovery is finally
>
> (E) raised hopes for a recovery finally

I assume that the answer the test preparers were looking for is (D).

Comment: Actually that would be *may not last*. the quoted sentence means that if there were not a large amount of spending the recovery (whatever it is) would not endure.